# how to pass multi query string of GridView with javascript

Tags: javascript, gridview

with below codes ,i can pass one query string of GridView to other page but i have 2 items which want to pass other page , thank if you help me in this matter

```
<DataItemTemplate>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='openpopup (&#039;<%#Eval("id") %>&#039;)' title="click">projects</a>
                    </DataItemTemplate>
```

javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function openpopup(id) {

            window.open("P-Add.aspx?id=" + id, "", "width=800 ,height=600");
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:?

```
<DataItemTemplate>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='openpopup (&#039;<%#Eval("id") %>&#039;, &#039;<%#Eval("param") %>&#039;)' title="click">projects</a>
</DataItemTemplate>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openpopup(id, param) {

        window.open("P-Add.aspx?id=" + id + "&param=" + param, "", "width=800 ,height=600");
    }
</script>
```